# Redirecting subdomains to other domains

Tags: domain-name-system, domains

I'm helping a friend set up a streaming service for a day and he's asked me a question that does beyond my knowledge of DNS. I'm hoping you can help.

We've been provided equipment that (when turned on) automatically streams through stream487.streamingcompany.com:8175. Now, this isn't bad, but we'd prefer to set something up so that our visitors who want to open the stream directly can type streaming.oureventdomain.com into a media player to have access.

We can (and will be) providing .pls files for easy streaming, but think the custom subdomain would be a nice touch. We have full access to the server on oureventdomain.com, but not much access to the streamingcompany.com stuff (Though they have been flexible).

Any ideas or help would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to redirect the request to a different port, rather than enabling a DNS redirect, point the subdomain to your server itself and do the redirect using your webserver to the stream url. eg,

```
Redirect permanent / http://stream487.streamingcompany.com:8175
```

in apache. If your domain is hosted on IIS, check the corresponding redirect module docs.

Answer (score 0):

in this case, you will need to setup a CNAME. So in the zone file for streaming.oureventdomain.com, you will have a line here:

```
streaming.oureventdomain.com.        CNAME  stream487.streamingcompany.com.
```

Comment: Will this cover the port bit too? Or will users need streaming.oureventdomain.com:8175?

Comment: No, you will still need to specify the port.